# Fano's Inequality Proof

Tags: markov-chains, information-theory, entropy

For an information theory class, I am studying the proof for Fano's inequality, i.e.:

$H(P_e) + P_elog(|X|) \geq H(X|\hat{X}) \geq H(X|Y)$

Where $H(X)$ is the [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_entropy_function) of the random variable X $\hat{X}$ is an estimate of the random variable X, and $P_e$ is the probability of getting it wrong. Also,

$X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow \hat{X} $ is a Markov chain.

I am following the proof from Cover and Thomas' Elements of Information Theory.

The first step is to define a random variable E:

$ E = 1 $ if $\hat{X} \neq X$

$ E = 0 $ if $\hat{X} = X$

Then these two equations I cannot explain are written:

$H(E,X|\hat{X}) = H(X|\hat{X}) + H(E|X, \hat{X})$;

$H(E,X|\hat{X}) = H(E|\hat{X}) + H(X|E,\hat{X})$.

The rest of the proof relies on these equations, but I do not understand how they are found; I imagine it is a simple application of the entropy chain rule and of the rule for conditional entropy, but I can't derive them from the general equations.

Could I get the step-by-step derivation of both, starting from $H(E,X|\hat{X})$? Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is just the chain rule for entropy.

The chain rule for entropy is Theorem 2.2.1 in Cover and Thomas.
$$H(X,Y) = H(X) + H(Y|X)$$
You can use the chain rule when you condition on another random variable $Z$. In this case, you get
$$H(X,Y|Z) = H(X|Z) + H(Y|X,Z)$$
The proof is word for word the same as the proof of the original chain rule. In this case, write each of the probabilities conditioned on $z$.  For example, write $p(x,y|z)$ instead of $p(x,y)$.

Or, alternatively, you can write something like this (as they suggest in Eqn. (2.20)):
\begin{align*}
H(X,Y|Z) 
 &= -E[\log p(X,Y|Z)] \\
 &= -E[\log p(X|Z)] - E[\log p(Y|X,Z)] \\
 &= H(X|Z) + H(Y|X,Z)
\end{align*}

With this version of the chain rule for conditional entropies, you get the two equations that you wanted by applying it to the random variables $X, \hat{X}, E$.

Comment: Could you please detail this step a step further? $-E[\log p(X|Z)] - E[\log p(Y|X,Z)] = H(X|Z) + H(Y|X,Z)$, and the E stands for $\sum_{x \in X}\sum_{y \in Y}\sum_{z \in Z}p(x, y, z)$ right?

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong, what confuses you is the chain rule of conditional entropy. Actually it is just the equivalence of such an equation: $p(x, y)=p(x|y) * p(y)$

Let me exemplify it with this:
$$p(E, X) = p(E| X) * p(X)$$
Along the same line, 
$$p(E, X| \hat X) = p(E |X, \hat X) * p(X| \hat X)$$
And we take the log of both sides and get, 
$$log p(E, X|\hat X) = log p(E |X, \hat X) + log p(X| \hat X)$$
Multiplying the above by $-p(E, X, \hat X)$, and we obtain,
$$-p(E, X, \hat X)log p(E, X|\hat X) = -p(E, X, \hat X)log p(E |X, \hat X) - p(E, X, \hat X)log p(X|\hat X)$$ 
And we can get,
$$-\sum_{e \in \mathcal {e}}\sum_{x \in \mathcal {x}}\sum_{x \in \hat{\mathcal {x}}} p(e, x, \hat x) log p(e, x|\hat x)= -\sum_{e \in \mathcal {e}}\sum_{x \in \mathcal {x}}\sum_{x \in \hat{\mathcal {x}}}p(e, x, \hat x)log p(e |x, \hat x) - \sum_{x \in \mathcal {x}}\sum_{x \in \hat{\mathcal {x}}}p(x, \hat x)log p(x|\hat x)$$
That is,
$$H(E, X|\hat X)=H(E, |X, \hat X) + H(X| \hat X)$$